# Dc.js Pie Chart Show all Values Between a Range Made by Another Field

Tags: javascript, mongodb, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I want to create a dc.js pie chart that is made up of different occupations and how many people had that occupation. The twist is that I also want the user to be able to input two numbers to act as a lower year bounds and upper year bounds. So for example the user can input the number 1650 and 1750 and is returned with a pie chart showing the percentage of occupations people had between 1650 and 1700.

I tried creating two different groups and trying to filter them using a fake group but kept hitting walls. I also tried having a dimension that featured both the occupation and year as a key but couldn't get them to group properly. Every time I'd just wind up with a pie chart showing the number of occurrences of a occupation for per year for the range.

[image: Here's the graph for the full range. It's only once the user tries to apply there own year range that it all goes wrong]

[image: Here's what I typically end up with when trying to implement the apply button]

Here's an example of the data that is being used:

```
{"borrowed_yr": 1747, "borrower_occupation": "Police Officer"}, 
{"borrowed_yr": 1747, "borrower_occupation": "Police Officer"}, 
{"borrowed_yr": 1747, "borrower_occupation": "Police Officer"}
```

I'm going to post the Javascript code however timeFrameChange() and timeGroupFilter() are both unfinished since that's where I tried to fix the problem the most. Also this is the code that caused the 2nd chart. For the first chart just delete " + "," data.borrowed_yr" from the occupationDimension line. Ask any questions as I'm not sure if I've explained this properly.

```
queue()
.defer(d3.json, "/db/occupationData")
.await(makeGraph);

var occupationChart;
var occupationGroupFiltered;
var occupationDateGroup;

function makeGraph(error, occupationJson)
{
    occupationChart = dc.pieChart("#occupation-chart");
    var occupationData = occupationJson;
    var occupationCrossfilter = crossfilter(occupationJson);
    var occupationDimension = occupationCrossfilter.dimension(function(data)
    {
        //console.log(data.borrower_occupation, data.borrowed_yr);
        return data.borrower_occupation + "," + data.borrowed_yr;
    });
    var occupationGroup = occupationDimension.group().reduceCount();
    occupationGroupFiltered = groupFilter(occupationGroup); //occupation 
                                                        filter dimension 

    occupationChart
            .width(1280)
            .height(800)
            .dimension(occupationDimension)
            .group(occupationGroupFiltered)
            .legend(dc.legend());

    occupationChart.render();
}

function timeFrameChange()
{
    var lowerRange = document.getElementById("lowerRange").value;
    var upperRange = document.getElementById("upperRange").value;
    document.getElementById("lowerRange").value = "";
    document.getElementById("upperRange").value = "";
    if(lowerRange < 1750 || upperRange > 1968)
    {
        document.getElementById("lowerRange").style.backgroundColor = 
                                                              "#800000";
        document.getElementById("upperRange").style.backgroundColor = 
                                                              "#800000";
        return;
    }
    document.getElementById("lowerRange").style.backgroundColor = "white";
    document.getElementById("upperRange").style.backgroundColor = "white";

    occupationGroupFiltered = timeGroupFilter(occupationGroupFiltered, 
                                              lowerRange, upperRange);
    occupationChart
        .group(occupationGroupFiltered)
        .render();
}

function timeGroupFilter(source_group, lowerRange, upperRange)
{
    return {
        all:function () {
            return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
                if(d.key > lowerRange && d.key < upperRange)
                {
                    return d.key;
                }
            })
        }
    }
}

function groupFilter(source_group) 
{
    return {
        all:function () {
            return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
                console.log(d)
                if(d.value > 10 && d.value < 6000)
                {
                    return d.value;
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Is there some reason you don't want to use an ordinary dimension filter for this?

Comment: I'm still pretty new to using crossfilter.js so I'm not really sure what you mean by an ordinary dimension filter. I though creating fake groups was the way to filter stuff for a chart but I assume there's another way?

Comment: No, crossfilter base functionality is all about filtering (thus the name ;) so I would first try creating an independent dimension for year, take the year out of the occupation dimension, and use [dimension.filterRange()](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_filterRange) to apply the date range. Use `dc.redrawAll()` to see the filter applied. See [the annotated stock example](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/stock.html) for a quick introduction to crossfilter concepts.